# Writing a PDO search query from a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm building an application using PHP 7 and a PDO connection to a MySQL database.

One part of the application contains a search form which allows a user to search for a training course by 3 different fields: the course category, the course name, and a date.

The types of elements on the form are:

1. Course category - dropdown, with numerical (int) ID's.
2. Course name - text input
3. Date - date picker (using HTML 5 `type="date"` parameter to get a calendar in the browser).

These fields can be used in conjunction, or on their own. This means a user could search, for example, just by (1), or (2 & 3), or all (1 & 2 & 3).

I've written the PHP to get the POST data and it's now in an array - for example:

```
$search_data = [
    'category' => 3,
    'name' => 'Hazard training',
    'date' => ''
]
```

I want to use this within a PDO query but I don't know what the best way to write it is because (1) and (3) would be an `=` query condition, whereas (2) is a `LIKE`. My solution was going to be looping through the search terms and then trying to construct a query, e.g.

```
$sql = ' WHERE ';
foreach ($search_data as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'category') {
        $sql .= ' category = ' . $value;
    }
    if ($key == 'course_name') {
        $sql .= ' course_name LIKE % ' . $value ' % ';
    }
    if ($key == 'date') {
        $sql .= ' date = ' . $value;
    }
}
```

The trouble with this is it doesn't work because of having to bind the parameters in PDO. It also doesn't work because I can't find a way to get the `AND` between each query (if there is a preceding statement).

I'm lost with this now and unsure what the best way to write this is.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I realise that hardcoding the names, e.g. `($key == 'course_name')` isn't ideal, but this is only being done because of the different query conditions (`LIKE` vs `=`). I assume that one could make `$search_data` multi-dimensional to say which type of query it was, but this is beyond my initial problem and probably another post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here`s a simple solution to your problem:

```
$sql = 'SELECT ..... FROM ... WHERE 1 ';
$where = '';
$pdoData = [];

foreach ($search_data as $key => $value) {
    if(!$value) continue; // skip empty values

    if ($key === 'category') {
        $pdoData[':category'] = $value;
        $where .= ' AND category = :category ';
    }
    if ($key === 'course_name') {
        $pdoData[':course_name'] = '%'.$value.'%';
        $where .= ' AND course_name LIKE (:course_name) ';
    }
    if ($key === 'date') {
        $pdoData[':date'] = $value;
        $where .= ' AND date = :date ';
    }
}

$sql = $sql.$where;

$stmt = $this->ci->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($pdoData);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And you have `$pdoDate` array holding the binded data.

Comment: I like the `WHERE 1`, making the construction easier.

Comment: I would change the `course_name` part to: `$pdoData[':course_name'] = '%' . $value . '%';` I don't think `LIKE % :course_name %` will work as intended...

Comment: use not empty  if ($key === 'category' &&  !empty($value))

Comment: I little improvement was made

Comment: You also need to escape any `%` in the input, otherwise, that will change the search (you won't be able to search for that character, but rather get a weird search result, since any extra `%` will be counted as part of the search pattern).

Comment: I don't understand how to use `$pdoData` because unless it contains all 3 parameters, PDO will issue an error saying the number of parameters doesn't match.

Comment: `$pdoData` will contain as many parameters as there are in the query. If statments in the foreach loop ensure that $pdoData will match the query parameters.

Comment: I'm using it like this: `$result = $stmt->execute([
                "category_id" => $pdo_data[':category_id'],
                "course_name" => $pdo_data[':course_name'],
                "date" => $pdo_data[':date']
            ]);
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: Ok, that's not working, but more likely to be something else in my query. I'll debug it and then post my findings. I've var_dumped everything to make sure the correct data is in the array too.

Comment: Print the whole query and add it here

Comment: Sorted it now. It was something else in my code (my own error). Thanks for your help, this works.